# memory allocated by NULL pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Does NULL pointer take any memory?
If it takes memory,then how much memory is consumed by it and what is the significant use of **NULL**  pointer if it takes memory?

Comment: Do you mean a _null pointer_ or `NULL`?

Comment: @Olaf  I think he specified NULL pointer .

Comment: @ameyCU: The is no `NULL` pointer according to the standard! [`NULL`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note66) is a macro, which **may** be a pointer, but can be any [null pointer constant](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3). A _null pointer_ is a pointer which equals the _null pointer constant_ and any other _null pointer_.

Comment: @Olaf  It may be considered as pointer to `0` or `(void *)0` I think.

Comment: @ameyCU: A "pointer **to** `0`" is not a _null pointer_ (injective, not bijective). However, my question is very relevant. The _null pointer constant_ does "take memory" as it has to be encoded in a instruction/literal - depending on architecture, Whie a _null pointer_ does not take extra space apart from the pointer itself,

Comment: @Olaf  As I read again , I made a mistake .I meant null pointer constant there . And  I agree pointer to that is Null pointer. Thanks  for correcting me :)

Comment: Everything in your program takes up memory. The linker is unable to store things in thin air.

Comment: I feel the question's wording is ambiguous, misleading, inaccurate, as any pointer, even a pointer pointing to `NULL` allocates memory itself namely for `T * p` `sizeof p` bytes, it however not necessarily *points* to any allocated memory. A pointer being equal to the `null`-pointer definitely does *not* point to any allocated memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pointer *value* (`NULL` or not) requires some amount of space to store and represent (4 to 8 bytes on most modern desktop systems, but could be some oddball size depending on the architecture).

The pointer value `NULL` represents a well-defined "nowhere"; it's an *invalid* pointer value guaranteed to compare unequal to the address of any object or function in memory.  The macro `NULL` is set to the *null pointer constant*, which is a zero-valued integer expression (either a naked `0`, or `(void *) 0`, or some other expression that evaluates to `0`).

After the code has been compiled, the null pointer constant will be replaced with the appropriate null pointer *value* for that particular platform (which may be `0x00000000`, or `0xFFFFFFFF`, or `0xDEADBEEF`, or some other value).

Answer (score 5):

Any pointer value, including `NULL`, takes a small, system-dependent amount of space to express or store.

That's an altogether separate consideration from any space that the pointed-to object, if any, may require.  A `NULL` pointer is guaranteed to not point to any object, but a non-`NULL` pointer is not guaranteed to point to an object. On the other hand, there may be more than one pointer to the same object.

Where a `NULL` pointer is intentionally used, it is typically used to explicitly express an invalid pointer, since you cannot tell from any other pointer value whether that pointer is valid.  This can be useful, for example, as a sentinel value marking the end of an unknown-length array of pointers, or as a function return value indicating failure.  The canonical example of the latter might be `malloc()`, which returns `NULL` if it fails to allocate the requested space.

Answer (score 3):

A `NULL` pointer doesn't allocate anything.  If you have a definition like this:

```
int *x = NULL;
```

That means the variable `x`, which points to an `int`, doesn't point to anything.  You can then check `if (x == NULL)` to see if it points to valid memory.

Comment: Well no, not exactly.  If `x == NULL` then you can be certain that `x` does not point to valid memory, but the converse is not true.  Determining that `x` is not `NULL` does not, in general, tell you anything at all about whether it points to valid memory.  There is a large number of ways to get an invalid, non-`NULL` pointer value.

Comment: Nit-picking on "*A NULL pointer doesn't allocate anything.*" Any pointer `T * p` *always* allocates `sizeof p` bytes.

Comment: @dbush this means that "int *x = 0" is a valid syntax to initialize that pointer ? But point's to an invalid memory ?

Comment: @Michi On systems where a NULL pointer is the value 0 it would be valid, but there's no guarantee that is the value.

Comment: @dbush What do you mean by "it would be valid" ? the pointer itself, or that the pointer point's to a valid memory location.

Comment: @Michi It means that it would be a valid way to say that pointer doesn't point to valid memory if the system uses a value of 0 as the NULL pointer value.